# Can I find integral of $e^x$ from its Taylor series expansion.

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, riemann-integration

I tried to do evaluate integral of $e^x$ from series this way 
I'm stuck :-
So where am I mistaken ???!
My solution here
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCp1R.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try it this way:

$\begin{align}
\int_c^xe^tdt&=\int_c^x\left(1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{3!}+\dots\right)dt\\
&=\int_c^xdt+\int_c^xtdt+\int_c^x\frac{t^2}{2}dt+\int_c^x\frac{t^3}{3!}dt+\dots\\
&=(x-c)+\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{c^2}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{x^3}{3!}-\frac{c^3}{3!}\right)+\dots\\
&=\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots\right)-\left(1+c+\frac{c^2}{2}+\frac{c^3}{3!}+\dots\right)\\
&=e^x-e^c
\end{align}$

Comment: How? Can you please explain the third step

Comment: I added a line, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

The $C$ in the answer is an arbitrary constant  and there is no difference between having $-1+C$ and having $C$. It is just a question of renaming the constant.

Answer (score 0):

Since the indefinite integral is determined up to a constant, we just need to set the constant $C'=C-1$.